# How to order by date defined on context model wagtail

Tags: wagtail

i am getting and error trying to order by a fecha_inicio_evento date field on my model https://gist.github.com/9d3e1b3874eb43e6932699b7ea4b13c6   this is the screenshot of my error https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyICK.jpg ,
can you give me a hand folks not sure what i do wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.specific()` at [line 23](https://gist.github.com/ivan-vilches/9d3e1b3874eb43e6932699b7ea4b13c6#file-models-py-L23) of your `models.py` like this:

```python
talleres = self.get_children().live().specific().order_by('-fecha_inicio_evento')
```